# Doesn't minimal subtraction alone solve the large log problem?

Tags: renormalization, effective-field-theory

Assume we have an amplitude regularized through Dimensional Regularization, of a theory with a scale hierarchy $m \ll M$.

If we renormalize the amplitude with an ***on-shell renormalization scheme***, performing the subtraction at the low mass scale, then the amplitude contains terms of the form

$$
\log \frac{E^2}{m^2}
$$

(ignoring the role of the coupling constant and possible powers), where $E$ is the relevant tested energy process. If $E \gg m$, terms like this are hazardous to the convergence of perturbation theory and need to be avoided.

On the other hand, if we renormalize the amplitude using, e.g., $\overline{MS}$, we have, instead, terms of the form

$$
\log \frac{E^2}{\mu^2}.
$$

Can't this fictitious $\mu$ be chosen of the order of $E$ in some sense and solve this problem? Why do we need RG improved perturbation theory?

The description above most likely contains serious mistakes and I am grateful for other corrections and insights.

Comment: "Can't this fictitious  be chosen of the order of  in some sense and solve this problem?" -- This *is* RG-improved perturbation theory.

Comment: @Andrew but how does the RG participate in this? Can't we just calculate the amplitudes using $MS$ and substitute 'something' for the $\mu$ above without running constants at all?

Comment: The final answer can't depend on $\mu$ because it's just an arbitrary parameter that you introduced to regularize the integral. So the $\mu$ dependence you wrote down in the log has to cancel with something. The thing it cancels with is the $\mu$ dependence of the running coupling constant.

Comment: @Andrew I don't believe that to be all there is to it since otherwise DimReg+MS scheme WITHOUT RGE would be meaningless, and it isn't. I think the answer to my problem have something to do with the following: without RGE, even if  MS 'solves' the problem with one of the scales, it can't simultaneously do it for the other hierarchic one (which perhaps appears relating renormalized couplings with physical ones?), and that's where RGE comes for the rescue. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I am wondering if what you have in mind is doing MS, with $\mu$ fixed to some value, and then fixing the couplings against experiments at this value of $\mu$. You can do that, and if you never change $\mu$ then you never explicitly have to run the couplings. But I think saying this is not using the renormalization group is fooling yourself, since you could have chosen any value of $\mu$ and made this procedure work. The RG is there even if you hide it under the rug. You will only be able to solve the large log problem at one energy scale with this process (which is just OS with an extra step).

Comment: In other words, I can maybe see how you would say that MS without the RG is meaningful, but if you take that attitude, then MS sure seems pointless to me.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need to hear: so unphysical renormalization schemes ARE meaningless without RGE???

Comment: Yes. I mean, you could define MS to use a specific value of $\mu$ and fix the couplings by matching against experiment at some scale. But this would just be a more complicated version of OS that doesn't buy you much. The point of doing the MS scheme is so that you can get to the RG equations.

Comment: @Andrew although it is evident that if one substitutes a value for $\mu$ to input experimental data for the observable what is being done is, in a sense, just OS with extra steps -- it was hard for me to conclude the remark from the previous comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andrew another question: and what about RGE with physical renormalization scheme? Is that sensible at all? Can the renormalization scale be a sliding one if it is defined as the point where the subtraction is made?

Comment: In OS you don't introduce the sliding scale, so you can't set up the RG with that scheme.

Comment: @Andrew Hi! Sorry for bothering with this again. But look at Peskin or Weinberg's approach to RGE. They use Dim-Reg with a renormalization scheme which defines amplitudes at a space-like renorm. point. To my understanding, this is only to avoid a complex divergence for zero mass particles, but the point being it is not a MS scheme. In any case, they then proceed to derive the RGE with the renorm. point as sliding scale -- in contrast with the program I described above (of, e.g.,Srednicki) which uses the dim-reg fictitious $\mu$ as sliding scale with a MS scheme.

Comment: @Andrew doesn't this hints that there may be a meaning to RGE with a physical renorm scheme?